# HTML --> Excel file. Include vba code in downloaded file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

I currently have a block of code that exports tables in my HTML body to one excel file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
    //getting values of current time for generating the file name
    var dt = new Date();
    var day = dt.getDate();
    var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = dt.getFullYear();
    var hour = dt.getHours();
    var mins = dt.getMinutes();
    var postfix = day + "." + month + "." + year + "_" + hour + "." + mins;
    //creating a temporary HTML link element (they support setting file names)
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    //getting data from our div that contains the HTML table
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var table_div = document.getElementsByClassName("dvData");
    var table_html = table_div[0].outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    var table_html2 = table_div[1].outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    var table_html3 = table_div[2].outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html + "<br></br>" + table_html2 + "<br></br>" + table_html3;
    //setting the file name
    a.download = 'exported_table_' + postfix + '.xls';
    //triggering the function
    a.click();
    //just in case, prevent default behaviour
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
```

When the excel file opens, I want it to have some vba code that automatically runs when the user opens the downloaded file.

Is this possible? If so, how do I "embed" the vba code into the excel file my code exports?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with the HTML string way of generating an Excel file. You *may* be able to do it using Office instead, and in my version of Excel, macros aren't enabled unless I save the file with an XLSM extension.

Comment: In addition to @Tim's excellent point (Office 2007 and higher requires an XLSM extension and format), your users would also need to set their macro security settings in Excel (Office 95/97 and higher) to be able to run unsigned macros, which would likely end in disaster. You would be better off making an Add-In that is digitally signed and that everyone can then install. (http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm)